# Chrome New Tab Page doodle/logo blocked

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I recently installed Ublock Origin, HTTPS Everywhere, and Privacy Badger. Now the doodle/logo is now blocked/removed from the new tab page. I have attempted to enable rules to restrict the blocking on chrome://newtab, but that did not seem to bring the doodle back. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please try disabling them all, then enabling one, testing the new tab to see if the doodle is blocked, then doing the same with the other extensions? That way you can see which extension is causing the issue

Comment: I have tried that, but it did not fix the issue

Comment: If you have disabled them all and it still doesn't show then the issue isn't with these extensions...

Comment: It only happened after I installed the extensions

Comment: That doesn't matter. If all the extensions are disabled and it still doesn't show on a new page load, the problem is not with the extensions